# Future Builder finishes getting data even though the queries are not done (Flutter-Firestore)

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I've created a flutter app that gets it's data from multiple sources, from a firestore database, and from some HTTP API Calls. I do know that you need time for these data to load into an application so I've built my widgets on `FutureBuilder()` However, sometimes the snapshot already returns a data before all data is loaded. Can anyone help to make the loader animation longer so that my UI won't bug out. Thanks so much.

Here is my main widget:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('this is homelist length: $homeList');
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: AppTheme.white,
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: getData(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                strokeWidth: 3,
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  appBar(),
                  Expanded(
                    child: FutureBuilder(
                      future: getData2(),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                          return Center(
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                              strokeWidth: 3,
                            ),
                          );
                        } else {
                          return homeList.isEmpty == false
                              ? GridView(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                      top: 0, left: 12, right: 12),
                                  physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                  children: List.generate(
                                    homeList.length,
                                    (index) {
                                      var count = homeList.length;
                                      var animation =
                                          Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(
                                        CurvedAnimation(
                                          parent: animationController,
                                          curve: Interval(
                                              (1 / count) * index, 1.0,
                                              curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn),
                                        ),
                                      );
                                      animationController.forward();
                                      return HomeListView(
                                        animation: animation,
                                        animationController:
                                            animationController,
                                        listData: homeList.elementAt(index),
                                        callBack: () {
                                          Navigator.push(
                                            context,
                                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                              builder: (context) => homeList
                                                  .elementAt(index)
                                                  .navigateScreen,
                                            ),
                                          );
                                        },
                                      );
                                    },
                                  ),
                                  gridDelegate:
                                      SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                    crossAxisCount: multiple ? 2 : 1,
                                    mainAxisSpacing: 12.0,
                                    crossAxisSpacing: 12.0,
                                    childAspectRatio: 1.5,
                                  ),
                                )
                              : Container(
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      SizedBox(
                                        height: 30,
                                      ),
                                      Container(
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          color: AppTheme.white,
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                              topLeft: Radius.circular(8.0),
                                              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(8.0),
                                              bottomRight: Radius.circular(8.0),
                                              topRight: Radius.circular(8.0)),
                                          boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                                            BoxShadow(
                                                color: AppTheme.grey
                                                    .withOpacity(0.8),
                                                offset: Offset(1.1, 1.1),
                                                blurRadius: 10.0),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                        child: Column(
                                          children: <Widget>[
                                            Text(
                                                'Welcome to DiabeatIS, your patients will be displayed here!',
                                                style: AppTheme.headline,
                                                textAlign: TextAlign.justify),
                                            Divider(
                                              color: Colors.black,
                                            ),
                                            SizedBox(
                                              height: 15,
                                            ),
                                            Text(
                                              'Simply ask your patient for their code, and click the button below, you will be taken to a screen where you can add your patients, and view their data afterwards!',
                                              style: AppTheme.subtitle,
                                              textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                                            ),
                                            RaisedButton(
                                              child: Text('Add Patients'),
                                              onPressed: () {
                                                Navigator.push(
                                                    context,
                                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                                        builder: (context) =>
                                                            AddPatient()));
                                              },
                                            )
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                );
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Here is the function for my FutureBuilder:

```
  Future<bool> getData2() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 200));
    return true;
  }

  Future<bool> getData() async {
    _getCurrentUser();
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000), () async {
      _getPatients(); // a function that involves two queries 
    });


    return true;
  }
```

Get Patient Function:

```
  Future<bool> _getPatients() async {
    homeList.clear();
    if (didLoadpatients == 0) {
      print('this is didloadpatients at start of func $didLoadpatients');
      var document = await db
          .collection('users')
          .document(mUser.uid)
          .collection('patients');

      document.getDocuments().then((QuerySnapshot query) async {
        query.documents.forEach((f) {
          uids.add(f.data['uID']);
        });
        didLoadpatients++;
        print('this is didloadpatients at end of func $didLoadpatients');
        for (var i = 0; i < uids.length; i++) {
          var userDocuments = await db.collection('users').document(uids[i]);
          userDocuments.get().then((DocumentSnapshot doc) {
            homeList.add(HomeList(
                imagePath: 'assets/fitness_app/fitness_app.png',
                navigateScreen: DVFitnessAppHomeScreen(
                  uid: doc.data['userID'],
                ),
                patientInfo: new PatientInfo.fromFbase(doc.data)));
          });
          print(homeList);
        }
        print(homeList);

        var document = await db
            .collection('users')
            .document(mUser.uid)
            .collection('notifications')
            .where('hasbeenViewed', isEqualTo: false)
            .getDocuments();

        final List<DocumentSnapshot> notifDoc = document.documents;

        notifications = notifDoc.length;

        await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 800));
        return true;
      });
    } else
      print('I am leaving the get patient function');
    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 800));
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: so you have two futures. You call the second aync function inside the first one to make sure that both data get loaded. Currently two futures run independently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 1:**

Seems like all you need is simply `await`.

```
 Future<bool> getData() async {
     await _getCurrentUser();
     await _getPatients();

    return true;
  }
```

---

You can use `Future.wait` to wait for more than one future at a time.

```
Future.wait([future1, future2])
```

See the doc [here](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-async/Future/wait.html).

Comment: Should I use it on my getData() or on the getPatient()? I'm unsure.. Thank you for replying!

Comment: seems like all you need is simple await call